# primefaces calendar close overlayPanel

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have an overlayPanel and this panel have a calendar.

```
 <p:overlayPanel hideEffect="fade" showCloseIcon="true" dismissable="true" >
        <h:form>
            <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="dateRangeFilterClass">
                <p:calendar value="#{cc.attrs.value.from}" showOn="button" pattern="#{dateFormat.onlyDateFormat}"
                            mask="true"  >
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" global="false"/>
                </p:calendar>
 </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:overlayPanel>
```

So when a user select a day the overlaypanel close. Thats my problem.
I need to use dismissable="true" because i need to missclick close.

Any have a solution this calendar - overlaypanel bug ?

I try to handle this with JS but failed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to open an [issue at PrimeFaces](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues), so they fix the problem.

Another way to solve your specific problem is to override the [bindCommonEvents function](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/overlaypanel/overlaypanel.js) of the OverlayPanel prototype where the dismissable logic is implemented. There you could check if click is on a datepicker and prevent the overlayPanel from closing. This solution looks like this (tested with PrimeFaces 6.1)

Create a file **overlayPanelFix.js**:

```
(function() {
  PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.bindCommonEvents = function(dir) {
    var $this = this;

    if (this.cfg.showCloseIcon) {
      this.closerIcon.on('mouseover.ui-overlaypanel', function() {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
      }).on('mouseout.ui-overlaypanel', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
      }).on('click.ui-overlaypanel', function(e) {
        $this.hide();
        e.preventDefault();
      }).on('focus.ui-overlaypanel', function() {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-focus');
      }).on('blur.ui-overlaypanel', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus');
      });
    }

    // hide overlay when mousedown is at outside of overlay
    if (this.cfg.dismissable && !this.cfg.modal) {
      var hideNS = 'mousedown.' + this.id;
      $(document.body).off(hideNS).on(
          hideNS,
          function(e) {
            if ($this.jq.hasClass('ui-overlay-hidden')) {
              return;
            }

            // do nothing on target mousedown
            if ($this.target) {
              var target = $(e.target);
              if ($this.target.is(target) || $this.target.has(target).length > 0) {
                return;
              }
            }

            // NEW PART: do nothing on datepicker mousedown
            var target = $(e.target);
            if(target.hasClass('ui-datepicker') || target.parents('.ui-datepicker').length) {
              return;
            }
            // NEW PART END

            // hide overlay if mousedown is on outside
            var offset = $this.jq.offset();
            if (e.pageX < offset.left || e.pageX > offset.left + $this.jq.outerWidth() || e.pageY < offset.top
                || e.pageY > offset.top + $this.jq.outerHeight()) {

              $this.hide();
            }
          });
    }

    // Hide overlay on resize
    var resizeNS = 'resize.' + this.id;
    $(window).off(resizeNS).on(resizeNS, function() {
      if ($this.jq.hasClass('ui-overlay-visible')) {
        $this.align();
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

It's a copy of the original function with additional "NEW PART" (see comments in function).

Integrate the script in your **facelet**:

```
<h:outputScript name="js/overlayPanelFix.js" />
```

Be careful with overriding things like that when updating to a newer PrimeFaces version. You always have to check if everything still works fine.

Comment: _"A hacky way to solve your specific problem is to override"_ That is not really hacky but a common way to change/adapt things next to creating a real patch and/or until it is 'fixed' upstream. The source IS open, so this is perfectly doable and maintainable

Comment: @AlexFire Made my day! Thanks dude perfect solution!